# Git Clone Failing in Windows Batch Script

Tags: windows, git, bash, ssh, gerrit

I executed this command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" clone ssh://<user>@<org>:<path to repo>` in Git bash terminal and in normal command prompt.

When executed in Git Bash terminal, the clone works fine, but while running it in command prompt, it gives following error.

`Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

I need to run git clone through windows batch script, that's why 
i need to make it run through command line. How to do that work ?

**Note** :-
1. Add public key to remote(gerrit) that was generated using ssh-keygen.

Answer (score 0):

Your SSH identity is not found while running from command line. Make sure that `%HOME%\.ssh` directory contains your keys.

Comment: yes it contains keys. I think if keys were not present, then it should not have worked though git bash also